# Watching for changes inside ng-repeat on mongoose update from different controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have come across a really specific problem, that I was wondering someone could help me out with.

So, I have a department controller which loads a mongodb collection and displays it inside a table with ng-repeat. Each document has a "edit" link to modify itself.  The edit link, opens up a modal box which is a different controller. I make a PUT request from the modal controller and successfully update the document on my server.

The problem is as soon as I get out of the modal box, my page shows old data until i refresh the page. Is there a way to "watch" the specific row of document in the ng-repeat area. I want to make sure the specific row gets modified right away after the update operation from different controller. A solution that I found already works is reloading the whole page & controller (so that the whole collection would be reloaded with GET, but that would use extra resource and doesn’t seem like the right way to solve it).

Here is the simplified code (I have commented the places where I think the changes should happen):

department.html:

```
<tr dir-paginate="department in departments">
    <td>{{department.id}}</td>
    <td>{{department.name}}</td>
    <td>{{department.office}}</td>
    <td>{{department.phone}}</td>        
    <td> <a href="#" ng-Click="modifyDept(department)"> Edit </a> </td>
</tr
```

departmentController:

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/departments'

        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.departments = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             console.log(" Not Doneee "+ status+data+headers+config);
        });

//I was wondering if I could set up a watch in modifyDept?? The modalInstance however creates a new modal with separate controller.
 $scope.modifyDept = function (depID){
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'partials/deptModal.html',
      controller: 'deptModalController',
      resolve: {
        depID: function () {
          return depID;
        }
      }
    });
};
```

modalController for 'partials/deptModal.html':

```
$scope.newID = angular.copy(depID);
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

$scope.modify = function () {
    $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/departments',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {
                newID: $scope.newID
            }

        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
             if (status === 200) {
             // I believe something could also be done here to notify the parent controller (departmentController) maybe via a service?
               notificationFactory.info("Successfully updated: "+$scope.newID.name)
            }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        notificationFactory.error("Error: Status Code "+status+". Contact admin if issue persists.")
        });
  };
```

This is the first time I am working with angular and I have a hunch I am supposed to use $watch & a factory/service but just dont know how.. Any kind of hint or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add scope: $scope to the options passed in $uibModal.open method in department contoller,

departmentController:

```
$scope.modifyDept = function (depID){
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'partials/deptModal.html',
      controller: 'deptModalController',
      scope: $scope,
      resolve: {
        depID: function () {
          return depID;
        }
      }
    });
};
```

Now you will have access to the scope of departmentController in the modalController. In the success callback in the $scope.modify method, you can update the department in $scope.departments with the new values.

Comment: After doing some reading on deep vs shallow copy on angularjs and passing by reference vs value, I was able to fix my problem. Thanks for the help!